# Facing issue with binding Data from JSON Object to <mat-select>

Tags: json, angular, angular-material, associative-array, angular7

I am having trouble in populating the drop-down list from the JSON Response object coming from the API..

1. component.ts code

   ```
   for (let k in keys) {
           this.form.controls['id'].setValue(data[k].name);
           console.log(data[k].name);
       }
   });
   ```
2. component.html code

   ```
   <mat-form-field>
       <mat-label>Select a User</mat-label>
       <mat-select formControlName="id">
           <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.data" >
               {{ opt.data.name}}
           </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
   ```
3. console.log(data)

   ```
   0: {id: 1, name: "User1"}
   1: {id: 2, name: "User2"}
   2: {id: 3, name: "User3"}
   3: {id: 4, name: "User4"}
   ...
   ```
4. console.log(data[k].name); //This is the data I need on drop-down

   ```
     User1
     User2
     User3
     User4
     ...
   ```

The console.log data shows the index on every object. My JSON Object is pretty simple though.
It looks like:

```
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "User1"
 },
 {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "User2"
 },...
]
```

Kindly let me know what am I doing wrong. Thanks.

**EDIT**
Here's working
[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select)

Comment: what is the options here in the <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.data" >?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd I have just edited the typo. Thanks for the edit. Its data, not options.

Comment: Is it solved now? or still facing issue?

Comment: @Rachit Check the posted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, your API response is a list so just bind that with a for loop to `Mat-Option`.

HTML Code:

```
<mat-card>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="add()">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Select a User</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="id">
                                               \/\/
                <mat-option *ngFor="let key of users" [value]="key">
                    {{ key.name }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <br/>
            <div fxLayout>
                <div>
                    <button
                    mat-raised-button
                    color="accent" [disabled] = "form.invalid">Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</mat-card>
```

TS Code:

```
getUsers(): void {
  this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
        this.users = users;
        console.log(this.users)
  });
}
```

[`Forked_Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-axlsdx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select a User</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="id">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of list" [value]="item" >
                {{ item.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Modify your TS file according to this :

```
list:any=[];
 getUsers(): void {
        this.usersService.getUsers()
        .subscribe(users => {

            this.users = users;
            const data: User[] = this.users;
            console.log('data',data)
            console.log("object",Object.keys(data));
            const keys: number[] = Object.keys(data) as any;
            console.log("keys",keys);
            console.log("users",this.users);
            for (let k in keys) {
                this.form.controls['id'].setValue(data[k].name);
                console.log(data[k]);
                this.list.push(data[k]);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have tried options and data both with the other edits.

Comment: Please share your full code of ts file also so, that I can help you

Comment: Here is how I have stored my JSON response into an array...   const data: User[] = this.users;
            console.log(Object.keys(data));
            const keys: number[] = Object.keys(data) as any;
            console.log(keys);

Comment: I've edited my code as per the info was given by you please try this and let me know is it working or not?

Comment: Thanks again. I have tried again. Still not working. Let me remind you that I am able to fetch the data which I need to display on console.log as mentioned above. All I need is to bind it into drop-down list.

Comment: I've edited my code please try to debug code using {{key|json}} and see what data are shown in the page and try to itrerate it according to that.

Comment: No data is displayed anywhere. Kindly check my updated post. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell me your JSON object is stored in which variable? variable data or variable key? in ts file according to that I'll figure out

Comment: It is stored in variable data as I've mentioned in my question.

Comment: okay then first in HTML file do like this before <mat-option> {{data|JSON}} if it prints data on the page before dropdown then please take screenshot of that and attach here.

Comment: I"ve updated code and it works perfectly to try it.